# ValueError: labels not contained in axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, valueerror

I have data of the form :

`IMP_START_TIME                         IMP_CLR_TIME        SERV_OR_IOR_ID
0       2017-02-28 23:59:32.8730  2017-03-01 00:11:28.7550    -1447310116
1       2017-03-01 00:00:09.1820  2017-03-01 00:01:06.9120     1673545041
...                          ...                       ...            ...
266863  2017-03-01 04:05:28.2200                       nan     2108335332
266866  2017-03-01 13:10:01.1600                       nan     -724153592`

I want to remove all the rows which have "nan" in the IMP_CLR_TIME column. For this I wrote the following code :

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\SIA_1_3_2017.csv',low_memory=False)
SID_ST_CT_col = df[['IMP_START_TIME','IMP_CLR_TIME','SERV_OR_IOR_ID']]

SID_ST_CT_str = SID_ST_CT_col.astype(str)                


SID_ST_CT_str.drop(SID_ST_CT_str.loc[SID_ST_CT_str['IMP_CLR_TIME']=='nan'])
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
ValueError: labels ['IMP_START_TIME' 'IMP_CLR_TIME' 'SERV_OR_IOR_ID'] not contained in axis
```

When I print the rows which have 'nan' in the IMP_CLR_TIME column using the following command, it works.But I am unable to figure out why I am getting such an error when I try to delete the same rows.

Comment: check whether you have spaces in the columns, look at the output from `df.columns.tolist()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
['IMP_START_TIME', 'IMP_CLR_TIME', 'SERV_OR_IOR_ID']

df = df.dropna(subset=['IMP_CLR_TIME'])
print (df)
             IMP_START_TIME              IMP_CLR_TIME  SERV_OR_IOR_ID
0 2017-02-28  23:59:32.8730  2017-03-01 00:11:28.7550     -1447310116
1 2017-03-01  00:00:09.1820  2017-03-01 00:01:06.9120      1673545041
```

For remove white spaces in columns names:

- add parameter `skipinitialspace=True` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) whitespaces in columns:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```